# check box checked values getting only last value in android

Tags: android, checkbox

When I toast value of `assignbranch` getting multiple elements in arraylist and checkbox is checked for last element only.

values in `assignbranch` are `[a,b,c]`. When toasting `assignbranch` why am I getting

```
[a,b,c]
[a,b,c,a,b,c]
[a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c]
```

**Code**

```
public class BranchUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BranchModel> {
    public ArrayList<BranchModel> EmployeesList;
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String>  assignbranch=new ArrayList<String>();;
    ArrayList<String>  branch=new ArrayList<String>();

    public BranchUserAdapter(Context context, int resource,    ArrayList<BranchModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        EmployeesList = objects;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            // new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
            holder.branchcheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            holder.branch = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.branchuser);
            holder.branchcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    BranchModel planet = (BranchModel) cb.getTag();
                    planet.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
            v.setTag(holder);
            holder.branchcheck.setTag(EmployeesList.get(position));
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).branchcheck.setTag(EmployeesList.get(position));
        holder.branchcheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    }
    BranchModel Employees = EmployeesList.get(position);
    final String sample=EmployeesList.get(position).getName();
    SessionManager session;
    session = new SessionManager(getContext());
    session.checkLogin();
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    final String id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = "http://zamzamapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Dept?"+id;
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        // final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        //"http://emservices.azurewebsites.net/Employee.asmx/CheckUserGet", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray empjson = obj.getJSONArray("DDL");
                    for (int i = 0; i < empjson.length(); i++) {
                        //Getting json object
                        JSONObject json = empjson.getJSONObject(i);
                        //Adding the name of the student to array list
                        assignbranch.add(json.getString("name"));

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for(int i=0;i<assignbranch.size();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<EmployeesList.size();j++){
                         if(assignbranch.get(i).equals(EmployeesList.get(j).getName())){
                        //that means object in second response exists in first response
                        holder.branchcheck.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hello"+assignbranch.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.getMessage();
            // hide the progress dialog
        }
    }) {

    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
    //   assignedBranch();

    holder.branch.setText(EmployeesList.get(position).getName());
    return v;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    public CheckBox branchcheck;
    public TextView branch;
}
```

Comment: Please invest enough time if you are really after an answer here. Align your code and try to correct typos

Comment: which toast you are talking about. there are two toast lines. please be specific and make code proper indent.

Comment: first toast and im not able to get all item checked..

Comment: it is taking because you are checking in Employment list. FIrst it will check asignbranch which is true, so it will print all the values of emploment lis and again it will increase the asignbranch and ahain prin values.

Comment: is any way to check selected elements..?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

Simple **move** **checkbox click listener** to outside of **getView's** if else condition.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        // new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.branchcheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        holder.branch = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.branchuser);

        v.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).branchcheck.setTag(EmployeesList.get(position));
}

 holder.branchcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                BranchModel planet = (BranchModel) cb.getTag();
                planet.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
            }
        });

BranchModel Employees = EmployeesList.get(position);
final String sample=EmployeesList.get(position).getName();
SessionManager session;
session = new SessionManager(getContext());
session.checkLogin();
HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
final String id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
String url = "http://zamzamapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Dept?"+id;
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    // final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    //"http://emservices.azurewebsites.net/Employee.asmx/CheckUserGet", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray empjson = obj.getJSONArray("DDL");
                for (int i = 0; i < empjson.length(); i++) {
                    //Getting json object
                    JSONObject json = empjson.getJSONObject(i);
                    //Adding the name of the student to array list
                    assignbranch.add(json.getString("name"));
                    if (sample.contains(assignbranch.get(i))){
                        holder.branchcheck.setChecked(true);
                    }*/
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<assignbranch.size();i++){
                for(int j=0;j<EmployeesList.size();j++){
                     if(assignbranch.get(i).equals(EmployeesList.get(j).getName())){
                    //that means object in second response exists in first response
                    holder.branchcheck.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hello"+assignbranch.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.getMessage();
        // hide the progress dialog
    }
}) {

};
// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
//   assignedBranch();

holder.branch.setText(EmployeesList.get(position).getName());
return v;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you... but no item is checked..can you clarify the error